# Incongruous use of the past perfect by the BBC?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, grammaticality-in-context

From a BBC article, March 2007

> **[Swiss dig world's longest tunnel](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/6471241.stm)**
> […] The amount of freight crossing the Alps in heavy goods vehicles has risen sharply over the last two decades. In 1990 an estimated 40m tonnes went by road, in 2001 that **had risen** to 90m tonnes, with further big increases expected by 2010.

Can you tell me why past perfect "had risen" is used. It should be "rose" as it is preceded by past tense "went by road." I mean action in 1990 comes before that of 2001.  So how is the past perfect possible? Please explain in detail.

Comment: You're partly right. In this sentence, "in" should be "by", as in, "... **by** 2001, that had risen to 90m tonnes". Your suggestion of using "rose" would mean that the amount of heavy goods vehicles rose (suddenly) in 2001. The intended meaning here is that the amount had been rising since 1990. For what it's worth, this isn't a carefully written sentence. It has a other mistakes in it too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about whether "went by" happened before or after "had risen". It's about how "had risen" happens before "in 2001". The timeline of actions, from earlier to later, is: "40m tonnes going by" -> "amount of tonnes rising to 90m" -> "reaching the year 2001".

A possible rephrased version would be: "When 2001 came, the amount had risen to 90m tonnes." Or "By the time 11 years passed, the amount had risen to..."

But the verb "came" in "When 2001 came..." (or "passed" in "By the time...") is not stated explicitly. It's implied. And using the past perfect instead of the simple past tense creates an oomph, an emphasis on the rise in volume -- it's a *stylistic* use of the tense, one might say.

Here's some other examples on stack exchange that talk about how the past perfect can emphasize or assume something:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132190/an-exception-to-the-past-perfect/132195
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199575/past-perfect-example-confusion
- [Are these tenses unecessary?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155826/are-these-tenses-unecessary)